# How can I do a cumulative count of IDs, sorted, in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID':[29951,29952,29953,29951,29951],'DESCRIPTION':['IPHONE 15','SAMSUNG S40','MOTOROLA G1000','IPHONE 15','IPHONE 15'],'PRICE_PROVIDER1':[1000.00,1200.00,1100.00,1000.00,1000.00]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

I want to add a new column that counts unique IDs. The final DF should look like this.

[image]

I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
df['cnt'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=True)
df
```

That's not doing what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df['cnt'], _ = pd.factorize(df['ID'])
print(df)
```

|  | ID | DESCRIPTION | PRICE_PROVIDER1 | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 29951 | IPHONE 15 | 1000 | 0 |
| 1 | 29952 | SAMSUNG S40 | 1200 | 1 |
| 2 | 29953 | MOTOROLA G1000 | 1100 | 2 |
| 3 | 29951 | IPHONE 15 | 1000 | 0 |
| 4 | 29951 | IPHONE 15 | 1000 | 0 |

Comment: Wow! that does work!! What is the comma and underscore for?

Comment: @ASH, the comma is used to "unpack" the results of the factorize() function into two variables. The first variable is "df['cnt']," which will contain the integer codes generated by factorize() for each unique value in the "ID" column. The second variable is represented by the underscore character "_," which is typically used as a placeholder variable in Python to indicate that a specific value is not needed or will not be used.

Comment: It definitely works. I was convinced it would be some kind of cumulative count thing, but this factorize thing actually did the trick! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
df['cnt'] = df['ID'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Output:

```
      ID     DESCRIPTION  PRICE_PROVIDER1  cnt
0  29951       IPHONE 15           1000.0    0
1  29952     SAMSUNG S40           1200.0    1
2  29953  MOTOROLA G1000           1100.0    2
3  29951       IPHONE 15           1000.0    0
4  29951       IPHONE 15           1000.0    0
```

Comment: This is great, and a bit more intuitive given my education/experience! Thanks for sharing!!